# netbeans 9 Source/Binary

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been using Netbeans 8.2 with JDK oracle64-1.8.0.144.

I am in the process of migrating to Apache Netbeans 9.0 (incubating) and AdoptOpenJDK. I have taken a project developed under Netbeans 8.2 and JDK oracle64-1.8.0.144 (Sources | Source/Binary format JDK 8 and Libraries | Java Platform 1.8 Oracle) and imported it to Netbeans 9.0. With same Sources and Java Platform options, everything worked as expected. I changed Java Platform to 1.8 AdoptOpenJDK.

Everything worked as expected. Next, I installed AdoptOpenJDK 11. I built my project in Netbeans 9.0 with Sources | Source/Binary format JDK 11 and Libraries | Java Platform AdoptOpenJDK 11. Running with java AdoptOpenJDK 11, java -jar myapp.jar works fine, but if I double click myapp.jar, I get “The java JAR file “myapp.jar” could not be launched” message.

I then build my project with  Sources | Source/Binary format JDK 8 and leave Libraries | Java Platform AdoptOpenJDK 11.  I get the warning:

> warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8.

Both java -jar myapp.jar and double clicking myapp.jar work fine. I thought Sources | Source/Binary was for source code compatibility.  Any idea what is going on?

Comment: This sounds as if the extension `.jar` is associated with an old Java version on your computer. It has nothing to do with NetBeans (as the "double clicking" happens outside of NetBeans)

Comment: I don't think that is it.  All works fine as long as Sources | Source/Binary is set to JDK 8.

Comment: Of course, because the generated .jar then works with Java 8 which seems to be the default Java registered with the `.jar` extension in your system. If you open a command line window and run `/path/to/java11/bin/java -jar myapp.jar` manually (instead of "double clicking" it) I'm pretty sure it will work - even when the Source Level was set to 11 inside NetBeans

Comment: Regardless of what java I am running .jar is associated with "jar launcher.app" 15.0.1. I said java -jar myapp.jar works.  Jar launcher.app has a problem with Source/Binary format JDK > 8.  I might expect this with java platform, but not Source/Binary.

Comment: I have no idea what that launcher.app is but apparently it uses Java 8 to run any jar file

Comment: NetBeans 9.0 does not support the use of JDK 11. [From their web site:](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/) **"Java 9 and 10 Support"**. NetBeans 10 is going to be released soon, and it will support Java 11.

Comment: I'll try installing java 10.  Just thought Source/Binary was for source compatibility.  Strange that it would affect like this.

Comment: I installed JDK 10.  I got the same result.  When I changed Source/Binary to JDK8, it worked fine.

Comment: Looking into this further, I think @a_horse_with_no_name is correct.  I think Source/Binary does more than just verify source for specified JDK.  Mac OS X "jar launcher.app" must be setup to not launch any jar after java 8.  Source/Binary JDK 8 must ID the generated jar as java 8.

Comment: The "binary" part controls on which JVM version the compiled classes will work. It maps to the `-target` parameter for `javac`

Comment: @PeterReam **Source/Binary Format** does not _"verify source for specified JDK"_; that is done through **Properties > Libraries > Java Platform**. You can verify this by setting both **Source/Binary Format** and **Java Platform** to JDK 10, and then including some JDK 10 feature in your source (e.g. **Optional.orElseThrow()**). The code compiles, as expected. Now set **Source/Binary Format** to JDK 8. The code still compiles, even though **orElseThrow()** does not exist in JDK 8! You must set **Java Platform** to JDK 8 to trap the use of a JDK 10 API feature in your source.

Comment: I had the 2 options reversed.

Comment: @skomisa you have it backwards.  I am now on JDK 11, netbeans 10.  I set JDK and Source/Bianry both to 11.  I introduced var v = 123.  It compiled fine as expected.  I changed Source/Binary to 9 and it got flagged (introduced in 10).  Having forgotten I had this reported here, I opened: https://superuser.com/questions/1429769/netbeans-java-platform-and-source-binary-format-inconsistency which includes additional info.